# C++ STL map, whose key is shared_ptr<struct tm>

Tags: c++, dictionary, shared-ptr

For one of my projects, I need to use shared_ptr to struct tm as the key to a STL map. Below is my testing code. In the for loop, there are two ways to create a shared_ptr: 1)  TmSPtr tm_ptr = std::make_shared(* tminfo); 2) TmSPtr tm_ptr(tminfo). Both can compile; however during run-time, the 2nd method throws an error: "*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f52e0222de0 *** Aborted (core dumped)", indicating that it tries to free memory that does not exist. I am still quite new to smart pointers, so hopefully can get some insight from the forum.

Apologies that I may have included more headers than needed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

typedef std::shared_ptr<struct tm> TmSPtr;

int main()
{
    cout << "\nTesting a map where key is a smart ptr to struct tm:\n";
    map<TmSPtr, int> price_series;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        struct tm * tminfo = localtime(&now);
        printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(tminfo));

        TmSPtr tm_ptr = std::make_shared<struct tm>(*tminfo); // TmSPtr tm_ptr(tminfo); would fail in run time

        price_series.insert(std::pair<TmSPtr, int>(tm_ptr, i));

        usleep(1000000); // 1 sec
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a shared pointer as your key instead the type itself?

Comment: I use price_series as variable name in the map. Actually I could have 1000 price series, all of which share the same time stamps. I think using struct tm is too expensive, isn't it. There is really only 1 series of time stamps. Hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Use `mktime()` and store a `time_t` (integer) instead. Using pointers as keys is a bad idea, using shared_ptrs as keys is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4):

[`localtime(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) says: "The return value points to a statically allocated struct ...". That means the memory is not on the heap, so should not be de-allocated.

Your first method works because it *copies* the structure.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to figure out why I can have 2 lines of print out like "Current local time and date ...". I thought I should have got only 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

Shared pointers delete their object when all references to that object go out of scope. This means the underlying object needs to be allocated using `new`. But your second method is pointing to a statically allocated  variable - which is destroyed automatically. The first method creates a copy of the object and so is safe.